# SSRS Select All Causes URL to Exceed Max Length

Tags: sql, web-services, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have about 250 items with IDs about 6-7 characters long. I have them organized into 3 classes with about 8 sub classes in each class. When using the report, users will have the ability to use cascading drop down lists to filter the list of items. However, when the report initially loads, the users want all items to be visible.

The report parameters are being passed via a URL to a web service that will retrieve data for me.

I have set up the items report parameter as a multiselect, but I have manually added the value "All" as the default parameter and have included "All" as a option in the list of resources using the following query:

```
SELECT 'All' as ItemID
UNION
SELECT itemID as ItemID
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT itemID
      FROM itemMaster
      WHERE (itemSubClass IN (@itemSubClass)) and itemClass IN (@itemClass))
      ORDER BY itemID) as derivedtbl_1
```

When my program logic detects 'All' as a parameter for items it does not filter any items and sends the full list to the report.

There are a few problems I have with this set up

1. The 'All' Selection appears buried in my list of items. i.e. (Select All) is first, followed by the numerical items, followed by 'All', followed by alphabetic items.
2. The (Select All) item still appears in the list because it is a multiselect parameter ad if the user selects it, all 250 items are selected and I receive the max URL characters error.

So, is there an easy way to allow for multiselecting items from that items list (within reason i.e. 10 max which would keep me under the URL error), disabling the (Select All) option, and moving my custom 'All' option to the top of the list in its place?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get rid of ALL. You need to manipulate the behavior of "SELECT ALL" to behave like ALL i.e. no filters applied in your URL. The way you can do is count the rows in your dataset and compare it with parameter count selection.

Something like:

```
=iif(Parameters!ItemID.Count=CountRows("ItemIDDataset"),"ALL",JOIN(Parameters!ItemID.Value, ", "))
```

Make sure when doing count comparison based on if you have removed "ALL" option.

Here are some helpful articles explain this scenario.

http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2844/working-with-multiselect-parameters-for-ssrs-reports/

http://dataqueen.unlimitedviz.com/2011/06/how-to-default-to-all-in-an-ssrs-multi-select-parameter/

HTH